# Boosted logistic regression - Explanation

Tags: regression, logistic, classification, boosting

Can anyone explain to me, please, the concept of **boosted logistic regression** in simple terms.I know what's the logisitic regression and all the "classic" classification algorithms. What I don't what it is is the concept of **boosting**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understanding, boosting is a way to convert a set of weak learners to a strong model. The weak learners specialize on different subsets of data. For example, you can iteratively build weak models. The subsequent models will do the classification task on the misclassified data. The final model can be a weighted sum of your weak models. With boosting, you can get better results since it can reduce bias as well as variance.